# Is it possible to have atomic batch updates in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, atomic

I am having an issue with mongo updates in my current project.We have a document pool maintained in MongoDB. A reader process fetches a batch of documents from this pool .In order to ensure that the documents from the DB are not fetched again,a status associated with each of the document is changed (say,from Arrived to Processing).

We are looking at scaling up and having multiple reader processes picking up different batches.However, as per as my understanding,mongo updates are not atomic on the batch.Is there any way I can look towards achieving this?I need to ensure that a document does not get picked up from the pool by a different reader before it is updated by the previous one.I am basically looking at atomic batch updates.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are doing something like this to update the statue:

```
db.docs.update({status:"arrived"},{$set:{status:"processing"}},{multi:true})
```

followed by a load of the documents with status:"processing".

There currently is no mongo incantation to update more than one but fewer than all matching documents.  You ether use `{multi:true}` for all documents or you only mark one document.

Given that, you might try marking arriving documents with a unique id for each reader process  with a non-multi update. Then read the document to process. The marking will atomically update one document with one reader's unique id thus avoiding contention between readers.

Something like:

```
db.docs.update({status:"arrived"},{$set:{status:"processing", readerId:<myid>}})
```

where `<myid>` is the unique id value for the reader process that issues this mongo update.

Then the reader can load docs with:
`db.docs.find({status:"processing", readerId:<myid>}}`

Comment: Thanks for the answerbut I don't think this would solve the problem.My problem is that I want the statuses of all docs in a batch to be changed atomically and adding a readerId does not seem to handle that problem.

Comment: With the one-or-all behavior of update you either have a batch size of one when marking or all the new docs will go to one reader.

Comment: On a second reading of http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/, I would say it's not at all clear what the result would be when more than one thread issues an update statement with the same query. The threads would be competing for the documents and it would all depend on what thread gets the write lock after a yield. There is an open issue on mongo to support update with limit: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `findAndModify` you can atomically find and update a document.

If you

```
db.docs.findAndModify({
    query : {'status':'arrived' }, 
    sort: { dateTimeOfdoc:-1},
    update : { 'status':'processing','transactionId':12345},
    new : true});
```

Whilst all threads are competing for the documents, because each document can be found and modified in an atomic operation, it means once a thread has it, it wont be fetched by others.

It's not a batch of docs as you wanted, but does it deal with your problem?